# How to use struct update syntax with immutable borrow?

Tags: rust

I am getting an error while creating an instance of struct using struct update syntax:

```
struct User {
    username: String,
    email: String,
    active: bool,
    sign_in_count: u64,
}

fn create_user(username: &str, email: &str) -> User {
    User {
        username: username.to_string(),
        email: email.to_string(),
        active: true,
        sign_in_count: 1,
    }
}

fn create_user_from_template(username: &str, email: &str, user: &User) -> User {
    User {
        username: username.to_string(),
        email: email.to_string(),
        ..user
    }
}

fn print_user(user: &User) {
    println!("username: {}, email: {}", user.username, user.email);
}

fn main() {
    let user1 = create_user("abcd", "abcd@gmail.com");
    print_user(&user1);
    let user2 = create_user_from_template("xyz", "xyz@gmail.com", &user1);
    print_user(&user2);
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:21:11
   |
21 |         ..user
   |           ^^^^ expected struct `User`, found `&User`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

Is this possible? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

`user` is a passed in as a reference to your `create_user_from_template` function, (as the `&User` type) so all you need to do it dereference it: `..*user`.

Comment: This will only work if user is `Copy` right?

Comment: I come from C++ background, so if I need to dereference does it mean I have to use `->` syntax to access the fields of struct.

Comment: @mousetail The user doesn't need to be, but I think the fields it pulls do, since Rust can copy/move only the needed parts of the struct

Comment: @Harry nope, Rust has certain auto-dereference rules, so you can continue to use the `.` operator and it will be able to handle it the same way `->` works in C++. literally just adding a `*` in front of `user` is all that needs to be changed. I'm actually a little surprised that isn't autoderefed.